# Magento Integrity constraint violation: 1062

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database

Currently i'm facing below error when i'm save any product on admin side. When ever i import new product or try to create new product and save it in admin. It's show error again and again . please help and post your suggestion

Error:-

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '186899-0-2' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`price` AS `final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tier_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`group_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`
```

`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp` Table Structure:-

[image: Structure]

`catalog_product_index_price_tmp` Table Structure:-

[image: Structure]

Comment: This Value ID " 186899-0-2" has a duplicate on that specific table. You should check that one.

Comment: I have already checked in both table and both are empty tables.

Comment: Can you please send a screenshot of your table structure in here? Thanks

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: What version of Magento 2 are you using?

Comment: I'm using magento 1.14.2.1 Enterprise Version.